# Problem with measurement error mitigation using VQE

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, measurement, vqe, error-mitigation

I am attempting to mitigate measurement error while running on one of IBM's real devices and am doing so by passing CompleteMeasFitter into `measurement_error_mitigation_cls` in QuantumInstance. However, when I run the program, I receive the following error:

```
qiskit.aqua.aqua_error.AquaError: 'The qubit mapping of circuits are different. 
Currently, we only support single mapping.'
```

I can see that the problem is coming from `get_measured_qubits_from_qobj` in `measurment_error_mitigation.py`. After a few iterations, the `measured_qubits` and `qubit_mapping` are not equal. I figured that the problem could be arising from the transpiler since the default optimization level is 1, meaning it will optimize based on connectivity. So, I tried changing `optimization_level` to 0 in quantum instance in hopes that `qubit_mapping` and measured_qubit will not be different, but have not had any luck.

How can I go about fixing this problem?